# What's a Good package for Phonetic Representation for Various Human Languages?

Tags: perl, translation, aspell, phonetics

I'm currently working on a project for which I think being able to come up with phonetic representations of words in various languages would be really helpful. I know Aspell does this pretty well, but I don't think there's a very easy way to get at their phonetic representations, so I ask: is there some other good package for getting the phonetic representation of a word given the word and the language/dialect/accent/whatever it's coming from?

This doesn't need to be in any particular language, but if it were Perl, that would be best.

I've already tried Soundex, Metaphone, DoubleMetaphone, and everything else in [Text::Phonetic](http://p3rl.org/Text%3a%3aPhonetic), and none of that stuff was very good – definitely nowhere near as good as the stuff in Aspell.

Comment: Is producing the phonetic pronunciation the end goal or a means to another end?

Comment: The means to another end. Ultimately, the goal is to use this in an implementation of a fuzzy-autocomplete algorithm.

Comment: Oh dear, that's hard.  Not the least of which because partial words can sound very different.  "t", "th", "thro", "throu", "throug", "through".  I suspect it would take a lot of training an AI for probabilities rather than using phonetics.  You might want to look for a service which provides that.

Comment: It is hard :) I think my idea works as long as I have a list of all possible phonemes that a word part can turn into (i.e. at the time that "throug" is typed, we should generate the phoneme for "ough" already, if that makes sense. Basically, having a list of text to phoneme conversions would do it for me. Aspell has that, but I was hoping someone already built an API for the phonetic part so I wouldn't have to do it myself.

I'll wait a bit longer, and if I still don't find anything, I'll just build one.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that springs to mind is [Soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex).  Of course, there is a Perl module [Soundex](http://p3rl.org/Soundex), too.  While this is designed to generate a soundex "key" from input it might be useful in mapping different variants to a common key.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned, I've already tried everything in Text::Phonetic, including Soundex. None of it is very good.

Comment: As the author of Text::Metaphone, I can say that it is not a very good representation of how things are pronounced.  Soundex is even worse.  They're more for going the other way, from hearing a pronunciation to looking up what word it might be.

Answer (score 1):

There is a package Text::Aspell in CPAN. Might be useful.

Comment: I noticed that before, but I can't figure out a way to interface directly with Aspell's phonetics representations through it :-\

Answer (score 0):

I you are trying to make a google style suggestion/correction system, it's not based on just phonetics or AI, but on a massive amount of user input. When a user makes a search, and doesn't click in any link but corrects the input and searches again, it gives google a lot of data about "correct" writing than a phonetics test or dictionary matching.
The main problem is in human language itself, it's not that people speak or write in a deterministic way, let alone in multiple languages.
Of course , i might be wrong, but if you need a library that let's you do this:

```
getLanguage(string);
```

I want to see that working, really.

Comment: Yup. Having a lot of user data is important as well. I already have that, and it's an important part of the system. Phonetic representation is an important part as well, and that's the part I don't have right now.

Comment: Well you are set for a good start, going the other way around is just painful.